# jQuery hover over child elements makes quirky effects

Tags: jquery, events, dom, event-bubbling

I've got this markup (simplified):

```
<div class='item'>
  <a> one link </a>
  <a class='trash'><img src='trash.png'/></a>
</div>
```

I'm highlighting the div when the mouse enters, and showing the (otherwise hidden) 'trash' link (it's like a tiny trash bin) so the user can delete the link.

I can't use 'hover' effect, because I need them to be **live** events. So I'm doing mouseover and mouseout. This is the code:

```
$('div.link').live('mouseout', function(e){
        console.log(e)
        if(e.target == this){
            $(this).removeClass('hover');
            $(this).children('a.trash').fadeOut();
        }
    });
```

(mouse over does the exacto opposite).

The animation looks quirky though, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `mouseover` and `mouseout` events are also fired when the mouse enters and leaves any child elements.  Try using the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events instead.

Unfortunately, the [live](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live#typefn) method doesn't currently support these methods.  You'll have to bind them manually when you add/remove links.

```
function toggleDelete() {
      $(this)[($(this).hasClass('hover') ? 'remove' : 'add') + 'Class']('hover');
      $(this).find('a.trash').toggle();
}

$('div.link').bind('mouseenter, mouseleave', toggleDelete);

$('.add').click(function(e) {
    var link = $('<a />').addClass('link');
    link.bind('mouseenter, mouseleave', toggleDelete);
    $('.parent').append(link);
});
```